# is there alerting can be done in nifi processor?

Tags: alert, monitoring, apache-nifi

in nifi, we can have a [PutEmail](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutEmail/index.html)  processor which can be configured for each flowfile. 
However, is there any mechanism or processor available to get alerting when any processor stops or processor is having an error?

how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [MonitorActivity](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.MonitorActivity/index.html) processor to alert on changes in flow activity.  MonitorActivity is designed to detect the absence of flowfiles through the processor.  When the condition is tripped, a notification flowfile is generated that you can route to a [PutEmail](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.PutEmail/index.html) processor.  MonitorActivity provides relationships for both the inactive notification and a notification for when activity is restored.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can able to see bulletin board to find error obtained any processors in right top corner of nifi UI.

No need for any other processor to perform alerting if any error then bulletin board shows error in which processor in ui.

[image]

Comment: alerting is possible for this bulletin board?